# How do I create this matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Consider a real matrix m and one of its rows r. Let su(r, m) be the sum of all elements on row r. I now want to create a matrix M that has one row and M(1, j) = su(j, m). How do I do this?

Comment: [`M=sum(m,2)'` or `M=sum(m,2);M=M'`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but I think you are looking for:

```
m = randn(10);   % m matrix
M = sum(m,2)';   % Sum of rows of M
disp(M)          % Display the result
```